# Images/Vector Assets now showing in ListView CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I am trying to make a custom list view with images and text so first I created a layout:

**custom_list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewProduct"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_teamwork" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Book Name" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Author"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coin"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/price" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="1000" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then I have an Activity which I am opening using Intents from another activity.

**ListingActivity.java**

```
package com.rishav.vitbooks;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

public class ListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "my_logs";
    ArrayList<Book> arrayList;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: init");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("User");

        Toasty.info(ListingActivity.this, "Welcome back " + email.trim(), Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

        arrayList.add(new Book("Fundamentals Of Physics", "H.C Verma",200));
        arrayList.add(new Book("Android Dev", "Sushrut dai",1000));
        arrayList.add(new Book("Name here", "Risav",1));
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_layout, arrayList
        );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_listening.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I can not see the vector assets in the list view though I do get the texts there as I wanted. I have both the `ic_teamwork` and `ic_coin` in my drawable directory. In fact if I change the content view from `activity_listening` to the `custom_list_layout' I can see the images but not when those are inflated into the list view.

Here is my **CustomAdapter**:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;

    public CustomListAdapter (Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Book> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.books = objects;
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, null, true);
        }

        Book book = getItem(position);

        TextView txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
        assert book != null;
        txtName.setText(book.getName());

        TextView txtAuthor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        txtAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());

        TextView txtPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(book.getSellPrice()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

If it matters I was trying to work on [this](https://github.com/quocnguyenvan/custom-listview-example) example.

Here are my gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rishav.vitbooks"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.rishav.vitbooks">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/DarkTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".ListingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HelpActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why can't I see the images/vector assets in the listview but can see them in the custom_list_layout? How do I fix this?

Comment: For both `ImageView`s you can use just `android:src="@drawable/ic_teamwork"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_teamwork"`

Comment: @Boken when using VectorDrawableCompat we need to use app:srcCompat according to the docs. And moreover I did try that :(

Comment: In which format do you have your images (vector or raster)? Is it `.xml` file in `drawable` directory? Or `.png` (or different raster graphics) in `mipmap`?

Comment: @Boken It is in XML yeah. I designed and exported the svg and created a new vector asset.

Comment: But anyway I have tried using a png as well with the app:src there still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

from your `build.gradle` (you have it 2 times!) file you can use `android:src` tag in your `xml` layout.

I created new vector file (in `res > drawable > ic_directions_boat.xml`):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#002F6C"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M20,21c-1.39,0 -2.78,-0.47 -4,-1.32 -2.44,1.71 -5.56,1.71 -8,0C6.78,20.53 5.39,21 4,21H2v2h2c1.38,0 2.74,-0.35 4,-0.99 2.52,1.29 5.48,1.29 8,0 1.26,0.65 2.62,0.99 4,0.99h2v-2h-2zM3.95,19H4c1.6,0 3.02,-0.88 4,-2 0.98,1.12 2.4,2 4,2s3.02,-0.88 4,-2c0.98,1.12 2.4,2 4,2h0.05l1.89,-6.68c0.08,-0.26 0.06,-0.54 -0.06,-0.78s-0.34,-0.42 -0.6,-0.5L20,10.62V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3V1H9v3H6c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v4.62l-1.29,0.42c-0.26,0.08 -0.48,0.26 -0.6,0.5s-0.15,0.52 -0.06,0.78L3.95,19zM6,6h12v3.97L12,8 6,9.97V6z" />
</vector>
```

[image: Boat]

And changed your (`srcCompat`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewProduct"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_teamwork" />
```

to (use my `xml` as `src`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewProduct"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_boat" />
```

I have such effect:
[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I literally spent hours solving this. But I still don't understand this. Why can't I use app:srcConpat instead. I have used it in MainActivity layout and it works there. Anyways thank you so much,